# How can you get Facebook Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm now trying [pynder](https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467), but it requries you to get a facebook ID and access token.

The facebook ID is what each user has in its own page, such as `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=YOUR_ID` if I understand it correctly.

However, I don't understand how I get the access token. I first tried to get with [this tutorial](https://www.slickremix.com/facebook-60-day-user-access-token-generator/), but since it is outdated, the actual pop-up page showed two types of ID: `Get Use Access Token` and `Get Access Token`. So I registered Facebook Developer program.

Then, I didn't know which to pick, but I tried both anyway. The page didn't show `read_stream`, by the way. However, I didn't get a correct response when running `curl`:

```
curl -X POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth --data '{"facebook_token": fb_token, "facebook_id": fb_user_id}'
```

This issued an error: `{"code":401,"error":"FacebookTokenRequired"}`.

How can I get the correct access token to run the program?

Comment: _“Then, I didn't know which to pick, but I tried both anyway”_ – both what? // Generally: You get a token by sending the user through the login flow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens If you only need one for testing purposes, you can also generate one in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: _“The page didn't show read_stream, by the way.”_ - well, that permission does not exist any more, btw. :p And you simply can not get the full user’s stream/newsfeed any more. Go read the documentation to find out what permissions are available and what they do.

Comment: @CBroe I meant I didn't know which to pick from `Get Use Access Token` and `Get Access Token`.

Comment: @Blaszard can you show us the full code for request, including app id.

Comment: @SagarV The code is only there; it is one line since I got the error there. Is it safe to share App ID here?

Comment: Replace app id and secret code if you added it with `xxxxxxxxxx`  or something

Comment: @SagarV But I'm not sure then what I should write here. Since App ID is only used to create an access token, and the access token can only be created via Graph Explorer API, it means I have no code to write?

Comment: @CBroe There's a **big** difference between `doesn't exist` and [`deprecated`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation)... Namely, deprecated things *still exist*. For example, I ended up here because I just got message **`"(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream"`** when calling `https://graph.facebook.com/me/home` ...now obviously that implies that there's something wrong with the call itself - which I have yet to figure out (being only an hour into the FB API), and I wpn't be the only one encountering it given the problem of out-of-date information online :-\

Comment: @ashleedawg read_stream _doesn’t_ exist any more, in the way that you won’t be able to ask any user for it any more. Same for /me/home btw., that has also been removed ages ago - removed in the meaning of you can not use that any more. You can name that however you want, fact is you won’t be using it any more, because that is impossible.

Comment: My point was that the FB graph API "asked" **me** for `read_stream`, so your prior comment could have beem confusing to others... I was clarifying that the API **is** asking for something that it's not going to get,

Answer (score 7):

the following link may help you
[Getting Facebook Access Token from User Id and Facebook App Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196667/getting-facebook-access-token-from-user-id-and-facebook-app-secret?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

Getting Facebook User access tokens:

Step 1: goto : [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Step 2: Locate and select Get Token in dropbox on right and copy the token from text Box
[image]

Bonus Step3 : To get User ID associated with access token : click the blue info icon at the starting of text box
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3):

You can get your access token through the [Facebook Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/)